# nested if statement jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to do a nested if statement or if else if statement in jsx. essentially if there is 1 input it has the label of Primary, if there are 2 inputs, the first one has label primary and second one has label of Secondary and if there are more than 2 the first has label as Primary, second as Secondary and 3 going forward have no label.

Currently my code puts label Primary on the first and Secondary on the second but as soon as I add a third it erases all labels. Any ideas would be awesome.

```js
  render() {
    const { lowerType, currentPerson, contact, index, type } = this.props;
    const isPrimary = index === currentPerson.getIn(['primaries', lowerType]);
    // const secondaryLabel = <label><b>Secondary</b></label>;
    const label = <label><b>{ isPrimary ? 'Primary' : 'Secondary' }</b></label>;
    return (
      <div className='field main-item'>
        { currentPerson.get(`${lowerType}s`).size <= 2 && label }
        <Input
          value={contact}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          placeholder={`Enter ${type === 'Email' ? 'an' : 'a'} ${type.toLowerCase()}`}
          type={type === 'Email' ? 'text' : 'tel'}
          style={inputRight}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: At which line is the desired behavior not happening?

Comment: `const label = <label><b>{ isPrimary ? 'Primary' : 'Secondary' }</b></label>;
    return (
      <div className='field main-item'>
        { currentPerson.get(`${lowerType}s`).size <= 2 && label }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the below condition, which will return the label only if currentPerson.get(`${lowerType}s`).size is less than or equal to `2`.

```
{ currentPerson.get(`${lowerType}s`).size <= 2 && label }
```

If you want don't want to erase the label, or give another text it would be better if instead of using `&&` you use `tertiary` operator over here.

```
{ currentPerson.get(`${lowerType}s`).size <= 2 ? label : 'third label' }
```

Comment: this seems closer to what I want to do, but it still removed the Primary and Secondary label from the first 2 inputs. What I am aiming for is 

<label>Primary</label>
<input/>
<label>Secondary</label>
<input/>
<input/>
<input/>
.... so any inputs added after the 2nd one do not have a label.

Comment: then you should just put `{ label }`. Why you are using the condition if you dont want to remove the `label` ??

Comment: Where do I put the { label } ?
The condition I thought was necessary because there is always 1 input which will have the label of Primary, when a second input is added, it is given the label of Secondary and when a third, fourth, fifth, input is added it just falls under the same label as the Secondary rather than have their own labels.

Comment: If you want more control, you can just use a function which returns the JSX and call it inside {}.

Comment: oh really? How would that be done? Sorry, newer to this JSX react/redux stuffs.

Comment: Just call the function inside `{ getLabel (currentPerson) }` and write a `getLabel` function which returns JSX. ex: 
getLabel(currentPerson) { 
  if(condition) { return `primary` }
  else return `secondary`; 
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150421/discussion-between-stuffedpoblano-and-anurag-singh-bisht).